# Handling a huge sqlite database in android

Tags: android, sqlite, android-sqlite

I wanted to know that if I am using a huge database of maybe a million entries or more, then how much time would it take to fetch results on main thread ? Should I use AsyncTask ... Or is there any other way to handle this ??

Comment: never do that on the main thread!!!

Comment: Haven't tried such things yet, but I would recommend to not use the main thread. Have a look at the CursorLoader

Comment: @Kody - How can I use them with SQLite, they are supposed to work with content providers if i am not wrong

Comment: Have a look at --> https://gist.github.com/casidiablo/1217628 :)

Answer (score 0):

This is a performance barrier of supreme magnitude...

My strongest advice is to host an online database server, and fetch from that server via JSON.

Comment: Thats a nice workaround, but I still would like to know how to implement it locally if due to any reason I have to implement it that way in future ..

Comment: Two years ago, I implemented the same solution as you. I made a 7MB predefined sql-lite database inside my app. Guess what? The download rate decreased with 56% in the preceding week! Why? Because of the extreme large APK-file generated.